# Consolidating PDF, Word and screenshots from multiple folders into single RMarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm looking for advice on how to approach a data retrieval and consolidation problem. I have a folder on my desktop with a further 600 folders within it. Each sub folder contains numerous Word and PDF files. I need to consolidate all these files into one logical HTML file in RMarkdown.

Ideally in the knitted output, there would be the title of the subfolder, followed by a screenshot of all files in that subfolder. Success would look like that, repeated 600 times.

I've come unstuck pretty quickly, and all my efforts can only produce illegible CSV looking outputs, as opposed to a clear view of each document:

```
directory_path <- getwd()
```

```
subdirectories <- list.dirs(directory_path, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)
all_files <- list.files(directory_path, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
```

```
length(subdirectories) 

for (file in word_files) {

  if (tools::file_ext(file) == "docx") {

    cat("File:", file, "\n")
    
    doc <- read_docx(file)

    content <- docx_summary(doc)

    cat(content, "\n\n")
  }
}
```

I clearly don't know what I'm doing. Could anyone kindly give me a steer on how to approach this problem?